# How to push to remote master when head has moved to new position by some one

Tags: git, clone, git-push

I am new to using git. I cloned the master, did some changes, and committed it. I wanted to push my changes to the remote server but I got an error.

I noticed that the the master has been updated by some one (since I last cloned/checkedout). Now I am not able to push my commits to the master.
My new commit is in a totally different directory, not touching any code in the original master branch.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Do `git pull` first.

Comment: why git pull?On my current working copy which I tried pushing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple diagram roughly showing your current situation:

```
remote master: A -- B -- D
local master:  A -- B -- C
```

You can see that you started by cloning `master` which brought in commits `A` and `B`.  Then you made a commit `C` on top of this.  But someone else made his commit `D` and pushed it to the remote `master` before you did.

You have two main options here.  You can either `git pull`, which will merge the remote `master` into your branch, or you can `git rebase` on the remote `master`.  If you go with merging (`git pull`), then do the following:

```
git pull origin master
```

This will leave the diagram looking like this:

```
remote master: A -- B -- D
local master:  A -- B -- C -- M
```

If you type `git log`, you will see that a new merge commit `M` has appeared in your branch, containing the changes from commit `D` on the remote.  You can can push your changes via the following:

```
git push origin master
```

This would leave the diagram looking like this:

```
remote master: A -- B -- D -- M'
local master:  A -- B -- C -- M
```

where `M'` is a different merge commit on the remote which you introduced.

The other option for you would be to *rebase* your local branch on the remote.  To rebase, do the following:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

or

```
git pull --rebase master
```

This would leave the diagram like this:

```
remote master: A -- B -- D
local master:  A -- B -- D -- C'
```

where `C'` is the commit you did possibly slightly altered.  Now you can push your work to the remote via:

```
git push origin master
```

which will leave the diagram looking like this:

```
remote master: A -- B -- D -- C'
local master:  A -- B -- D -- C'
```

You'll notice that if you go with the rebase option that both the remote and local history are identical, and that the history is clean and easy to read.

Comment: @Raulp If no --rebase, `git pull` may cause a non-fast-forward merge on the local branch if you have updated your local branch with one or more new commits and someone else has updated the remote branch before your pull. Some teams may take a strategy to refuse any new push with a merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pulling? If the files you changed are different than the files changed in the remote branch, Git should be smart enough to figure it out.

```
git pull
```

Comment: there is a web which shows all the activity of pushing there.It generally changes when you refereshes it , and you can see the  latest commit. and the committer.I cant see my commit there.Any way I am cloning again.(git clone)

Comment: Since you're working on a completely different directory, `git pull` should merge your changes with the remote. Then you may need to `commit` again to save the merged code and finally `push`.

Comment: I dont need to commit here.I have done it already.I just need git pull and push .

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. As ElpieKay commented on Tim's answer, sometimes git pull will create a merge commit - looks like this time it did not.

Comment: May be because my commit has nothing to do with the original directory structure.Its a complete new folder I have commited.